# I want to add the members on Google Groups by Email

Tags: php, google-groups

Actually, I want to add the email address automatically join on my google groups by emailing on mygroupname+subscribe@googlegroups.com. But the issue is, when i email from php code to my group email for add. The google first send the reconfirm email to the user email and if direct email from hotmail,yahoo or gmail then google directly add the person as a member.

My Question is: Is this any php email code which works like the second scenerio i.e. add the person directly on group. I used PHP Mailer gmail smtp also but on that case, it adds the smtp user email not the email address which i set on From ? Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide us source code for email you've sent to GG ? I think that problem is in it's headers/data.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is on Google's side, not php's Google must confirm the user wants to be added, and confirm the email address is valid.