# Google Group and Subscription code

Tags: php, subscription, google-groups

I am new to programming in any field. Just started I have a task for adding a subscribe button.

What I have:

1. A Google group mailing list
2. A Website
3. I don't have a Google App engine.

Requirement: Very simple - A Subscribe button in the website which can auto subscribe people to the mailing list.

Language: PHP, HTML. Don't ask me about the coding, I suck now but not for long.

Comment: googled all the place.. but I really do not know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Emails sent to your-group+subscribe@googlegroups.com will auto-subscribe the sender to the group. So you could simply have a HTML link like:

```
mailto:your-group+subscribe@googlegroups.com?subject=Subscribe%20to%20Your%20Group
```

it requires a few extra clicks by the user but it's a fairly automated way of handling the subscribes, it ensures you've got the users true email address (because they're sending the email from it) and it requires no backend programming work on your part.

Comment: This only works though if the user is using a local email client like Outlook or Thunderbird.  `mailto` links aren't any help for people who only use webmail.

Answer (score 2):

```
<h3>Subscribe to <?= $group_title ?></h3>
<form action="http://groups.google.com/group/<?= $group_name ?>/boxsubscribe">
<input name="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="sub"/>
<a href="http://groups.google.com/group/<?= $group_name ?>">Browse Archives</a>
</form>
```

With $group_title, and $group_name set accordingly.  $group_name can be determined from the url when viewing your group.